# How to add category axis title in amcharts stock charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, amcharts

Here is the demo of my graph in Amcharts.[Working Pen](http://codepen.io/RKR3/pen/xReEGx)

Here I have included

```
"panels": [{
        "titles": [{
              "id": "Title-1",
              "size": 15,
              "text": " Taxi State Analysis"
            }],
            "categoryAxis": {
                "title": "Time spent in Minutes",

              },
        "stockLegend": {}
      }]
```

The chart title works fine but the category axis title did not appear. I also tried

```
"categoryAxesSettings": {
    "minPeriod": "mm"
    "title":"Time in minutes "
  }
```

This also did not work.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: your pen only says loading....

Comment: Could you check it now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to show the value axis title since that only make sense after looking into your code pen. Let me know if i am mistaken here.

you can do that using below properties.

```
  "panelsSettings": {
   "marginLeft": 50
   },

  "panels": [{

    "valueAxes": [ {
    "title":"Time spent in Minutes"
    }],
    "titles": [{
          "id": "Title-1",
          "size": 15,
          "text": " State Analysis"
        }],

    "stockLegend": {}
  }],
```

Code Pen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mOgrKp

Comment: This is perfect.But I also wanted to add the x-axis title as "Time".Can I do that?

Comment: x axis already have the time value , i think you will need legend for that.